# Zabbix+Telegram Action (2ble message)

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, zabbix

Stackoverflow. I use mediatype Telegram+telegram alertscript [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAB91.png). Then i make Action on Zabbix
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxasR.png).
If i shutdown 1 port on my switch. I get a 2ble message from Telegram Bot like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kXjT.png).

I don't know hot to fix this problem. And get only one message from the bot.